# Powershell | Check Folder for last written by new File

Tags: powershell, monitoring

I am looking for a method to monitor a windows folder for the last time a new file was written.

(If 1 day no new file is written in the folder, I want to write output...)
I cannot use the "last written" date from the folder because the folder is processing some stuff and renaming files.

Problem:
This folder is only used as a cache. The good files are immediately copied to another folder.

I want to use the script output for Checkmk

I tried already monitoring the Folder and written Files, but both get overwritten.

Comment: "The script should stop after reporting the state and finish after... so I cannot use a hash table." Can you explain this in more detail? Those two statements appear... unrelated

Comment: "the last time a new file was written." Do you mean the most recent file creation? regardless of whether the file still exists?